# Convert string to list and data in curve bracket to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a string value that I want to convert to a list. Also once it's converted to a list, I want this kite to act as a variable

```py
control_bag="[["A",("A","B","S","D"),(8,8,kite),(2,2,1)]]"
```

So, what I am looking as to change the string control_bag to list and kite will be a variable. The result in curve bracket will act as tuple

```py
control_bag = [["A",("A","B","S","D"),(8,8,kite),(2,2,1)]]
```

I have tried `json.loads`, but its causing error due to curve brackets

Comment: As long as this data is not coming from a potentially malicious source, you can just say `control_bag = eval(control_bag)`.  "Curve brackets" are called "parentheses".

Comment: @HenryEcker - `ast.literal_eval` is the way to go for this sort of situation, but the `kite` variable inside the literal makes things tricky.

Comment: @TimRoberts eval(control_bag) worked for me like a charm.